# Adding an array as a new key-value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an existing array which contains key-value pairs for a series of items:

```
resultsArray = [
  {
    parkName: "Central Park",
    owner: "NYC" 
  },
  {
    parkName: "Patterson Park",
    owner: "Baltimore"
  }
]
```

I'd like to add an additional key-value pair to each item where the value is an array of amenities. For example: if Central Park includes a dog park, jogging trail, and basketball courts, and Patterson Park includes a baseball field and a rec center, when the amenities were added to the array, the resultsArray would now look like:

```
resultsArray = [
  {
    parkName: "Central Park",
    owner: "NYC",
    amenities: "Dog Park", "Jogging Trail", "Basketball Courts"
   },
  {
    parkName: "Patterson Park",
    owner: "Baltimore",
    amenities: "Baseball Fields", "Recreation Center"
   }
]
```

I'm relatively new to Javascript, but I've successfully created an array of amenities for each of the parks. I then tried to add each amenityArray as follows:

```
resultsArray.push({
  amenities: amenityArray
});
```

However, this didn't give me what I wanted.

Can someone demonstrate how I would add the amenityArray as a key-value pair for each of the parks?

Comment: array should be wrapped with bracket: `amenities: ["Dog Park", "Jogging Trail", "Basketball Courts"]`

Comment: That data structure with each object with one incremented numerical key is weird. Why aren't you creating the array like this `resultsArray = [{
      parkName: "Central Park",
      owner: "NYC"
      }, {
      parkName: "Patterson Park",
      owner: "Baltimore"
      }]` If it is changed to this, you could just loop through the array using `forEach` and add `amenities` to each object

Comment: @adiga: My mistake. the array doesn't have the leading numerical values. That was a sign of my novice level. I'll edit them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each object in `resultsArray`, add the corresponding amenity.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
    resultsArray[i][i]['amenities'] = amenityArray[i];
}
```

A more verbose version would be

```js
for (let i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
    let result = resultsArray[i];  // i is an index
    let innerResult = result[i];  // i is a key
    innerResult['amenities'] = amenityArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and add a new key-value pair in the inner objects.

**Note:** Picked the amenities dynamically.

```js
resultsArray = [{ 0: { parkName: "Central Park", owner: "NYC" } }, { 1: { parkName: "Patterson Park", owner: "Baltimore" } }];
amenities = { "0": "X Park, Y Park, Z Park", "1": "A Park, B park, C Park" };
[...resultsArray].forEach(token => {
    Object.keys(token).forEach(key => token[key]['amenities'] = amenities[key]);
})
console.log(resultsArray);
```

Comment: Why `[...resultsArray]` instead of just `resultsArray`?

Comment: Both will do. `[... x]` notation will spread over the values and is useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.forEach()` to loop through the array and set each item depend on index:

```js
var resultsArray = [{parkName: "Central Park",owner: "NYC"},{parkName: "Patterson Park", owner: "Baltimore"}]

var amenityArray = [["Dog Park", "Jogging Trail", "Basketball Courts"], ["Baseball Fields", "Recreation Center"]];

resultsArray.forEach((val, index) => {val.amenities = amenityArray[index]})

console.log(resultsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` for this:

```
const newArray = resultsArray.map((item, i) => {
  item[i].amenities = amenityArray[i];
  return item;
});
```

Also your array structure looks weird, you should consider removing those redundant nested objects, and then it will be easier to iterate:

```
resultsArray = [{
    parkName: "Central Park",
    owner: "NYC"
  },
  {
    parkName: "Patterson Park",
    owner: "Baltimore"
  }
]

const newArray = resultsArray.map((item, i) => {
  item.amenities = amenityArray[i];
  return item;
});
```